# Trying to Permission Request for notifications Error Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, notifications

I'm trying to use Pushjs.org for quick fast notification system but for some reason Chrome keeps telling me that while using `Push.Permission.request();`

> Permission for the Notification API may no longer be requested from a cross-origin iframe. You should consider requesting permission from a top-level frame or opening a new window instead

I'm not sure what this meant so I used the regular notification request using

```
Notification.requestPermission()
```

But it also returned the same thing. I tried doing some research and was unable to figure how what the right way of asking user for permission would be.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Chrome you cannot request the Notification API, unless the site is `https`secured and also you cannot request it from a cross-origin iframe.

If you do meet this requirements, you should be able to use notifications and background push notifications on Chrome.